# Unhandled exception when inputting string from binary file | VisualStudio

Tags: c++, string, unhandled-exception

Alright, I'm a bit new to this so apologies if my question seems stupid.

Basically, I'm trying to read from a binary file into a string.
The code:

```
using namespace std;
fstream words;
words.open("Data/words.bin", ios::binary | ios::in);
string s;
words.read((char*)&s, sizeof(string));
cout << s;
words.close();
```

Compiling this gives me the following error:
`Unhandled exception at 0x0FABDF58 (msvcp120d.dll) in HangMan.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x052DE6EC.`

However it does print the string to the console before throwing up the error.

Writing to the file does not result in any sort of error though nor does reading a char[]. The problem only occurs when reading into a string.

EDIT:

I kind of knew that it isn't a good idea to cast string* to char* but I understand now. Its just that following code works, so I assumed using a string would also work:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class foo
{
private: 
int X;
int Y;
int Z;
char C;
public:
    foo(int x,int y,int z, char c): X(x), Y(y), Z(z), C(c){}

void display()
    {
        cout<<X<<endl<<Y<<endl<<Z<<endl<<C<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    fstream out;
    out.open("file.bin", ios::binary | ios::out);
    foo var(1,2,3,'a');
    out.write((char*)&var,sizeof(foo));
    cout<<"var: \n";
    var.display();
    out.close();
    cout<<"var2 before reading: \n";
    foo var2(0,0,0,'z');
    var2.display();
    fstream in;
    in.open("file.bin", ios::binary|ios::in);
    in.read((char*)&var2,sizeof(foo));
    cout<<"var2 after reading: \n";
    var2.display();
    return 0;

}
```

If I understand right, this shouldn't work either correct?

@Rakibul Hasan: I checked both the questions, not a duplicate.

Comment: how compiling can give any error?

Comment: "Writing to the file does not result in any sort of error though..." - honestly, if this code is how you're trying to read it, I wouldn't bet the farm that statement about writing is true without seeing it. You may want to post *both* operations (preferably in an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)).

Answer (score 1):

You are casting a `string*` to `char*`, which is invalid.

Comment: I'm casting the address to char*. This works fine for other data types. If I replace every mention of "string" with "int". This exact code works flawlessly (given the file exists).

Comment: if casting works fine, then it is by chance. `char*` and `string` are two totally different things and *string->char** is invalid. You can use the *char** contained in a `string` though, like `s.c_str()`.

Comment: @user3690467 You're casting a non POD-type to a raw pointer and blasting over its in-memory data image. Its *undefined behavior* to do so.

Comment: Note that as OP poited out, he's actually casting a `string*` to `char*`. Which is of course also invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Casting from `string` to `char*` is a very bad idea:

```
string s;
words.read((char*)&s, sizeof(string));
```

You need to allocate memory first. If you want to read file in one shot (only for small files):

```
size_t fileSize = words.seekg( 0, std::ios::end ).tellg() - words.seekg( 0 ).tellg();
std::vector<char> buf( fileSize );

words.read( &buf[0], buf.size() );
```

Comment: I understand. I added some code to the OP. Basically if I create a class myself and cast customclass* to char* in much the same way, the program writes and reads from file flawlessly. But it shouldn't.. If I'm not mistaken, would like to know why it does work!